# What argument 'isinstance' takes on declaring 'k' object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, isinstance

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x_or_obj = 0, y = 0):
        if isinstance(x_or_obj, Point):
            self.x = x_or_obj.x
            self.y = x_or_obj.y
        else:
            self.x = x_or_obj
            self.y = y

m = Point(1,2)
k = Point(m)
```

So I have difficulties with understanding why `isinstance` evaluating `True` in this code. I see it as `int` is checking against `class`, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: `m` is a point... you're passing it into the constructor when creating a second Point?

Comment: `m = Point(1, 2)` is going to `else` block and `k = Point(m)` is going to `if` as expected. What doubt do you have ?

Comment: I don't get what value ends up in ```x_or_obj``` when I pass ```m``` as an argument

Comment: it's either an `int` or a `Point`, depending on what you pass to it. Both cases occur above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this article about `isinstance`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp):

> The isinstance() function returns True if the specified object is of the specified type, otherwise False.

In `m`'s definition:

```
m = Point(1,2)
```

You're passing `1` as the value of `x_or_obj`. `1` is an integer, not a `Point`, therefore it evaluates to `False`.

However, in `k`'s definition:

```
k = Point(m)
```

you're passing `m` as the value of `x_or_obj`. You earlier defined `m` as type `Point`, so `isinstance` evaluates to True.